# PHP Default content type?

Tags: php, http, http-headers

It seems PHP defaults to content type text/html if not explicitly set otherwise.  Is there a global setting for this somewhere?

Is there any documentation regarding this?  I looked at http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php and found no mention of a default or related settings.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to change the default you can edit the [default mimetype](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.default-mimetype) in the [`php.ini`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php).

Comment: Exactamundo.  There should be mention of these settings in the header() docs page if you ask me.  thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Depending on your needs, you could consider adding a setting in Apache like this:

```
AddType my/content-type .php
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html#AddType